# Mercurial Clone Error

Tags: mercurial, clone

Everytime I try to clone my repo from my local laptop to my testing server (using ssh), the .hg directory is the only thing that clones, and the source never gets copied. Im not sure what could be causing this, since this is unusual behavior. Any ideas?

Thanks

**Local**

```
app
sys
.hg
```

**Clone Command**

```
hg clone repo ssh://user@host/repo
```

**Server After Clone**

```
.hg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected.  See `hg help clone`:

> It is possible to specify an "ssh://" URL as the destination, but no .hg/hgrc and working directory will be created on the remote side. Please see "hg help urls" for important details about "ssh://" URLs.

If you log into the server after the clone, you should be able to run `hg update` in the remote repository to create the working directory.